# OpenBSD - isolation on Desktop application level

Tags: desktop, openbsd, privileges

Which usable method is preferred as application isolation on OpenBSD?

- Running GUI apps with different users? Different for the webbrowser, torrent client, PDF viewer, etc.
- chroot? - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/karsten/entry/openbsd_chroot?lang=en
- Or are there other usable methods?

Purpose: If an attacker comes in via the webbrowser, then it shouldn't reach the (personal) files (ex.: pw manager DB file), memory content, it should be limited somehow.

Answer (score 1):

One could use a different user account to run the web browser (and a different X11 server for that different user, so there's no sharing between your regular account and where the browser is run).

Another option may be `vmm(4)` in which case you'd run an OpenBSD virt and run the troublesome applications therein. Graphics accelerated or otherwise might be tricky (no idea here, none of my CPUs are new enough to use `vmm(4)`)

Some applications are pledged (read `pledge(2)`), which may limit their access to resources. Others are hopelessly not pledged, so that's no help. (Compare chrome vs. olden versions of firefox.)